# Maximum number of concurrent request to MarkLogic REST service

Tags: marklogic

When trying to make a lot of sparql query requests through the rest api, our app eventually receives ECONNREFUSED during connect. I am just wondering if there is any configuration setting to adjust the limit. We will try to limit the number of concurrent requests performed by the app as well but want to know what the limit should be.

Answer (score 3):

The `threads` setting on the appropriate app server is related to this. It might not be a direct relation, but if number of threads is 32, you can only process 32 requests concurrently maximum (or more likely less).

That same section also has the `concurrent request limit` setting, but that is zero by default, meaning unlimited.

HTH!

Comment: More detail: `concurrent request limit` controls the number of requests an individual user can make to an app server concurrently (i.e., a request before another request has completed). See [Limiting Concurrent Requests with User Session Limits](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/session-login#id_52253)

Comment: The `threads` setting may help somewhat. I set the `threads` to different values and tried making concurrent requests to the server. With the setting as 100, our application can make 200 concurrent requests to the server without getting the error. However, if I allow 300 concurrent requests to the server, some requests will get the ECONNREFUSED error. In any case, the `threads` setting can only be set to a max value of 256 and it seems to have an adverse effect on performance when the value is too high.